Problem with name production for a label control
Private Sub DisplayCalendar()
    Dim FirstDay As String
    Dim LastDay As String
    Dim iDay As Integer
    Dim ctl As Label
    
    Dim DaysArray(7) As String
    
    DaysArray(0) = "Mon"
    DaysArray(1) = "Tue"
    DaysArray(2) = "Wed"
    DaysArray(3) = "Thu"
    DaysArray(4) = "Fri"
    DaysArray(5) = "Sat"
    DaysArray(6) = "Sun"
    
    FirstDay = Format("1/" & Month(SelectedDay) & "/" & Year(SelectedDate), "ddd")
    lastnumday = Format(DateSerial(Year(SelectedDate), Month(SelectedDate) + 1, 0), "dd")
    iDay = 1
    For i = 0 To 6
        If DaysArray(i) = FirstDay Then
           fdaynum = i
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    j = 1
    
    For iDay = 1 To lastnumday
         ctl.Name = "lbl" & DaysArray(fdaynum) & j
         [ctl].Caption = iDay
                 
         If fdaynum = 6 Then
            fdaynum = 0
            j = j + 1
         Else
            fdaynum = fdaynum + 1
            
         End If
    Next

The problem is in the line 'ctl.Name = "lbl" & DaysArray(fdaynum) & j'
I'm trying to make a calendar in ms access and I want to change the caption on each label with the day number. I receive the error:Object variable not set (Error 91)

You need to assign something to ctl.

Why change Name property? Calendar in Access db is a common topic. Many examples. Here are a couple https://download.cnet.com/microsoft-access-calendar-form-template/3000-2065_4-77364272.html and https://download.cnet.com/microsoft-access-calendar-form-template/3000-2065_4-77364272.html

You must retrieve the labels from the Form's Controls collection (assuming that the labels are directly on the form and not inside another control). Controls("lbl" & DaysArray(fdaynum) & j).Caption = iDay

Instead of
ctl.Name = "lbl" & DaysArray(fdaynum) & j

you should use assign the label control to your variable:
Set ctl = Me("lbl" & DaysArray(fdaynum) & j)

